# Resize a photo without loosing the correct size in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I'm capturing a photo using this code

```
m_photoFile = Capture.capturePhoto(1920, -1);
```

CN1 is not enforcing the 1920 width, at least in Android handsets. So I need to manually resize and store the Image to match my 1920x1080 requirement.

If I try this, my pictures are getting disorted.

```
photoFileImage = photoFileImage.subImage(0, 0, 1920, 1080, false);
OutputStream fos = fss.openOutputStream(m_photoFile );
imageIO.save(photoFileImage, fos, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 1);
```

I want my picture to be resized and any excess croped... 
So if I have a width of 1920x1100 those extra 20 pixels in the height, I want them croped... if posible 10 at the top, 10 at the bottom....

I'm not positive on how I could do that...

Please help
Thanks!

Comment: Also, both photoFileImage.getHeight() and photoFileImage.getWidth() are returning 0 for -----Image photoFileImage= Image.createImage(m_photoFile);  -----

Comment: What's the device and how big are the images created by it? Android is a bit tricky since some devices can capture images that are so large they can't be loaded.  We have a lot of builtin workarounds for those oddities but something might have broken in recent updates. I would suggest not using subImage or similar scaled calls as those would load the entire image to RAM and could be very expensive. Try to always use ImageIO for anything captured from the camera https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/util/ImageIO.html

Comment: Thank you Shai, I promoted the sugestion from Diamond about the scaledLargerRatio... that worked for me... I have to display the Image at screen anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String m_photoFile = Capture.capturePhoto();
Image image = Image.createImage(m_photoFile);
if (image.getWidth() > image.getHeight()) {
    image = image.scaledLargerRatio(1920, 1080);
    photoFileImage = image.subImage((int) (image.getWidth() - 1080) / 2, 0, image.getHeight(), image.getHeight(), true);
} else {
    image = image.scaledLargerRatio(1080, 1920);
    photoFileImage = image.subImage(0, (int) (image.getHeight() - 1080) / 2, image.getWidth(), image.getWidth(), true);
}
```

Comment: This works in simulator, though in the Android handset both image.getWidth and image.getHeight are returning 0 to me :(

Comment: public Image scaledLargerRatio(int width,in height) -- Scales the image while maintaining the aspect ratio to the larger size image || Nice found, this is useful.

Comment: It seems I'm unable to vote for the answer... though I used the scaledLargerRatio without the w>h comparison and is working for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: There should be a "disabled" checkbox next to the answer that you can click to accept it